# Installing Ubuntu as VM on XEN Server Free

Tags: virtualization, xen

I have installed and setup Citrix XEN Server 6.0 Free on my home computer and i need to install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on it.

But i cannot install it.I tried using CD Drive and NFS stored iso but all fails with error

**

> "Your Installation CD ROM couldnt be mounted.This probably means that
>   CD ROM is not in the Drive"

**  \
It fails in step 3 ie

> Detetct and Mount CD ROM

even after i tried 4-5 times

Do i need to install any support package for installing VMs on XEN **OR** should i need to upgrade xen to 6.02 for latest ubuntu support??

Used the same iso for installing many VM using XEN type 2 Hyperviosr on ubuntu

Comment: Question; is your iso correct (md5 sum it) and are you using the virtual disk

Comment: Also are you using Xen or Citrix XenServer?

Comment: yes created virtual disk,and used the same iso for installing VM before.

Comment: using Citrix XEN server 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When booting you will need to press F6 and disable ACPI (needs to be NOACPI). This should be fixed in the latest version I think.

Comment: ohhh...no.... you solved it again :) :) Thankx alot